# Append 0 to a number of the cell in Excel sheet

Tags: excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel show leading zero in formula bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644789/excel-show-leading-zero-in-formula-bar)

I am using an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) sheet for automation. Whenever i write a number such as `0428537` in a cell of the Excel sheet, it changes to `428537`.

How can I avoid without truncating the leading zero?

Comment: It may be duplicate but the topic is difficult to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is for presentation purposes, you can change the format of that cell to a custom format `0000000`.

If you want the actual content of the cell to be 0428537, then it can't be a number and you need to change the format of the cell to text.

Comment: Ya it worked when i changed to text format....this is what i require for my automation to work...Thanks assylias

Answer (score 0):

You can enter a number with 0 like

```
'0123
```

Start number with Single Quote ('), but now it will treat as text not number