# ADD number with 0 in front in ms excel?

Tags: excel

Can anyone let me know on how to maintain a '08' or '09' etc.. in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), because when i type in 08 and save it becomes 8.

I want to maintain 0 in front of the decimal

Comment: exact duplicate of [Excel show leading zero in formula bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644789/excel-show-leading-zero-in-formula-bar)

Comment: @brettdj: That's VBA. I believe OP is looking for a non vba solution (I could be wrong though)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sid the first part of that post refers to the `custom formatting` and `'` solutions before moving to code

Comment: Yup I saw that but that solution (adding "`") is not feasible if there are many rows. The easiest would be to right click and format the column?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes :), but that part was also covered in the post. This question is a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right Click on the cell and click on format cells. In the Format Cells dialog box, under the tab "Number", select Custom and type `00` and you are done.

See snapshot below.

[image]

**EDIT**

Your question talks about two things

1. Can anyone let me know on how to maintain a '08' or '09' etc.. in ms excel.Because when i type in 08 and save it...it becomes 8 AND
2. I want to maintain 0 in front of the decimal.

Which are two different things.

For the second point if you are looking for an output like  `.80` then again right click on the cell and click on `Format Cells`. Under `Number` Tab, this time go to "Number" and set the decimals there.

Comment: @Siddhart...Am using a .csv file so when i close the file the formatting is gone again

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot save the formatting to a csv file. That is the default nature. Either you can save it as an xls/xlsx file or re do the entire thing again (with or without macros). one other alternative is to write a macro which will append "`" before all values and then you can save it?

Comment: Luckily for me just found out that its maintaing the 0 when opened with a normal text editor like notepad++.So now my file parsing Java application shud read it without any issues..Thanks Sidharth for the help..